# SQL preparing a string for the smalldatetime convertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I'm new into SQL and I'm trying to manipulate a string which I m gonna convert to a smalldatetime later on.

The startString is `2017-9`and the datetime format should be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

I know how to convert it and I know how to add the `-dd hh:mm:ss` to the string. 
**BUT** how do I change the `9` to a `09`? Is there any special function or should I write a script which also checks if the number already has 2 digits? What would you suggest me?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] is this? [tag:sql-server]?

Comment: at what point do you want to change the 9 into 09? Before converting to datetime? And why?

Comment: Sql-Server 2014.

Comment: Yes before converting it to datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could Try Below `SQL` Script :

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DATA = '2017-9';

SELECT CASE
           WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(@DATA, 6, LEN(@DATA))) > 1
           THEN @DATA
           ELSE STUFF(@DATA, 6, 0, '0')
       END;
```

Result :

```
2017-09
```

Comment: Sorry for not clearing which DBMS it is. It's SQL-Server 2014

Comment: Just one more question please. Now it fails at the convertion. Error: `Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.`, what is going on? I have no clue. The code is: `convert(smalldatetime, concat(CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(datum, 6, LEN(datum))) > 1 THEN datum ELSE STUFF(datum, 6, 0, '0') END, '-01 00:00:00'), 120)`

Comment: @basilmonti wht data pass in <datum>

Comment: @basilmonti i think ur <datum> has not something about '2017-09' or 
'2017-9' or may be passing some values like '2017' or nothing ... which is unexpected for `date-time` conversation.

Comment: I m trying to convert 2017-09-01 00:00:00 to smalldatetime

Comment: @basilmonti no issue if you have '2017-9' or '2017-09' in <datum>... i checked & giving me right result as `2017-09-01 00:00:00` but u must know about the <datum> wht u passing there...

Comment: It should be '2017-9', I dont get it. I m trying to debug it

Comment: I m also using a the EOMONTH function.

Answer (score 0):

For getting it before conversion to datetime, try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN (DateValue) = 6 THEN '0' + RIGHT (DateValue, 1) 
            WHEN LEN (DateValue) = 7 THEN RIGHT (DateValue, 2)  
       END AS Period
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `CONCAT, substring and LPAD` which may help you:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    substring('2017-9',1,5),
    LPAD(substring('2017-9',6,2),2,'0')
  )

//Output: 2017-09


SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    substring('2017-10',1,5),
    LPAD(substring('2017-10',6,2),2,'0')
  )
//Output: 2017-10
```